# Windows 10 system proxy keeps getting enabled automatically

Tags: windows-10, proxy

My Windows 10 system proxy keeps getting enabled to a specific proxy setting at 127.0.0.1:41091. The proxy was previously set by a VPN app. But even after I uninstalled the VPN app. The system proxy is still getting automatically enabled every few minutes. I have tried scanning with bitdefender and malwarebytes, didn't find anything. What could be the probable cause and how can I stop this.

I have even tried deleting from the registry anything related to that port.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it looks like there is some process running that keeps setting it.

I would look into following places in registry if there isn't any leftovers from the VPN app:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Look into to `Startup` folder:

- %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
- C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Open the `Services` (or type `services.msc` on `cmd`) and look if there isn't anything related to the VPN app. If yes you can remove it using the `sc` command in `cmd`.

Another option is to open `Task Manager`, click the `More details` in the bottom (if not done already), got to `Details` tab and look for some process with similar name of that VPN app. You can also right-click the Column names, and add the `Command line` column which will show you the path the process is running from.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looked at Registry and Startup folders. Found no leftover related to the VPN App I uninstalled. I can see lots of programs running in Task Manager, I don't observe anything related to the VPN App either. For other processes I am not sure where to look in order to find the program changing proxy settings.

Comment: @Shawn what was the VPN app?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by uninstalling a small program in the system. Turns out it contains some spam ware which was detected by MalwareBytes. Thanks again for the tips.